# Node crypto createDecipheriv throws Invalid key length error

Tags: node.js, cryptography, rsa

Hi All: I am using NodeRSA to generate a private-public key pair by the following lines:

```
const key = new nodeRSA();
key.generateKeyPair(2048, 65537);
```

And after removing the header and footer and `\n`, the pair looks like this:

```
//only for demo
"publicKey": "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAlJ3PpWq77KY+tFccFfH4bO65Nu82LyzX0FxYGZ/QaF+LuZqeXEErXUO5iJ3P+hPRtiHUEHr9d5mfqStA/DnXxBbFmbwatNE8ncu4pSBOr9pbUyt22BRVkaiBBN0IuzBwo4ZWNrsON7IolVJnh8BKyurO5r7uj3aa8Yz0wcwIIkgais967iFWoj8YyeMSXpqUuMQu4mvcWB0EY/+wJNQnlSf7WuoJaTtzPzLe0qBaGnYO01ASxeOgPRzAJJ8prz2xZ5xy1nW+w+88XHVQsQizJ32B5Mzw7CpAeKIAnhlMVs8gVVc7iCfiwLoMiZXSReNxl2WfIYbHpaH2e6kPZoYNLQIDAQAB",


"privateKey": "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"
```

I use the above public key to encrypt some data and later decrypt by the above private key (convert to buffer) by the following lines:

```
// ivBuf is the buffer of initialization vector
crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', privateKeyBuf, ivBuf);
```

But Node crypto complains:

```
crypto.js:235
  this._handle.initiv(cipher, toBuf(key), toBuf(iv));
               ^

Error: Invalid key length
    at Error (native)
    at new Decipheriv (crypto.js:235:16)
    at Object.Decipheriv (crypto.js:232:12)
```

Question is: why key lenght is invalid?

Thanks!

Comment: You are creating an AES decipher with a RSA key. You have forgotten to mention the AES key in your question or you are using the wrong method. Probably you need `crypto.privateDecrypt(private_key, buffer)`

Comment: @pedrofb yes, you are right, I thought it in the wrong way, but got it solved already, will delete the question soon.

Answer (score 0):

The default string encoding used by the crypto module changed from binary to utf8. So your binary string is being interpreted as utf8 and is most likely becoming larger than 16 bytes during that conversion process